# Inconsistent results for equivalent converging symbolic integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, assumptions

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

I have looked at previous questions and I'm aware that this seems to be a known bug: *Mathematica* giving inconsistent results for symbolic integrals done in different ways. The origins for the bugs seem to be varied.

I'm having a hard time tracking down *where* Mathematica is going wrong with this particular one, especially since I am explicitly assuming that all my variables ($L$ and $\rho$) are positive. I've played around with the assumptions without any luck. Here's my code:

```
$Assumptions = {ρ > 0, L > 0};

limits = Sequence[{ux, 0, L}, {vx, 0, L}, {uy, 0, ux}, {vy, 0, vx}]

N1 = Integrate[a1 = Exp[-ρ (ux - uy) (vx - vy)], limits];
N2 = Integrate[a2 = Exp[-ρ (ux - uy) (vx - vy)] (ρ (ux - uy) (vx - vy)), limits];
N3 = Integrate[a3 = Exp[-ρ (ux - uy) (vx - vy)] (ρ (ux - uy) (vx - vy))^2, limits];
N4 = Integrate[a4 = Exp[-ρ (ux - uy) (vx - vy)] (ρ (ux - uy) (vx - vy))^3, limits];

int1 = Integrate[4 ρ (a1 - 7/2 a2 + 2 a3 - 1/4 a4), limits]

int2 =  Simplify[4 ρ (N1 - 7/2 N2 + 2 N3 - 1/4 N4)] // Expand
```

Apologies for the large expressions but the particular simplifcations only happen when all four integrands are included with the correct factors. By comparing integrands it's easy to see that `int1` and `int2` are the same integrals. But for `int1` I get

```
(1 - E^(-L^2 ρ)) L^2
```

whereas for `int2` I get

```
L^2 - E^(-L^2 ρ) L^2 - (7 L^4 ρ)/4 + 7/2 L^4 ρ Log[L]
```

I know that the outcome for `int1` is correct whereas that for `int2` is incorrect.

Any thoughts would be very welcome.

Comment: @belisarius I updated it.

Comment: Please don't use the `bugs` tag when you post a new question.  This tag has a special use and it's only added after the community (or WRI support) has agreed that it's really a bug ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks, noted.

Comment: Actually it wasn't so easy for me to see that the two integrals are really the same (and also check that you didn't make a typo) because the code is rather large.  So I edited your post a bit to make this very clear.  Please check the edit!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it's much clearer now. I double-checked it.

Comment: Re-added the `bugs` tag in view of my answer. Please let me know if someone thinks otherwise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug, of course. Mathematica gets dizzy by the "hanging" integration order (I believe).

As simple as it is, it was tough to find out but it gives the right result if you just change the order of `limits`:

```
$Assumptions = {ρ > 0, L > 0};

limits = Sequence[{ux, 0, L}, {uy, 0, ux}, {vx, 0, L}, {vy, 0, vx}];
(* instead of 
limits = Sequence[{ux, 0, L}, {vx, 0, L}, {uy, 0, ux}, {vy, 0, vx}]
*)

N1 = Integrate[a1 = Exp[-ρ (ux - uy) (vx - vy)],                            limits];
N2 = Integrate[a2 = Exp[-ρ (ux - uy) (vx - vy)] (ρ (ux - uy) (vx - vy)),    limits];
N3 = Integrate[a3 = Exp[-ρ (ux - uy) (vx - vy)] (ρ (ux - uy) (vx - vy))^2,  limits];
N4 = Integrate[a4 = Exp[-ρ (ux - uy) (vx - vy)] (ρ (ux - uy) (vx - vy))^3,  limits];

int1 = Integrate[4 ρ (a1 - 7/2 a2 + 2 a3 - 1/4 a4), limits]

int2 = FullSimplify[4 ρ (N1 - 7/2 N2 + 2 N3 - 1/4 N4)]

(*
 (1 - E^(-L^2 ρ)) L^2
 (1 - E^(-L^2 ρ)) L^2
*)
```

Comment: As a side note, each of the `Nx` gave a Complex result when evaluated with the original `limits` sequence

Answer (score 2):

I have isolated a simplified instance of the bug:

```
a = Exp[-(ux - uy) (vx - vy)] ((ux - uy) (vx - vy))^2;
i1 = Integrate[a, {vy, 0, vx}];
Assuming[ux > 0,
  i2a = Integrate[i1, {vx, 0, 1}, {uy, 0, ux}];
  i2b = Integrate[Integrate[i1, {uy, 0, ux}], {vx, 0, 1}];
  i2b - i2a // FullSimplify
]
```

which gives `4 I \[Pi]` (incorrect) rather than `0` (correct).

We can trace the likely source of this bug by inspecting the first integral `i1` which is `(2 - Gamma[3, (ux - uy) vx])/(ux - uy)` - i.e. a pair of terms each of which has a pole at `uy = ux`, but which have oppositely-signed contributions so they cancel out.

However, this cancellation does not occur when the subsequent integrals are evaluated as a single `Integrate` - i.e. `i2a` - where it seems that the oppositely-signed contributions become same-signed contributions.

So the bug seems to be inconsistent handling of the 2 contributions to the (illusory) pole at `uy = ux` when the integral is evaluated as a single `Integrate`.