# Inconsistent results for symbolic trigonometric integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, trigonometry

I am trying to evaluate (on Mathematica v.9) the integral 
\begin{equation}
\int_0^x [\sin (x) \sin (2 y)-\sin (2 x) \sin (y)]^t \,\mathrm{d}y, 
\end{equation}
where $t$ is an even, positive integer. Since Mathematica seems to be reluctant to perform the definite integral, my strategy is to compute the indefinite one first and then manually substitute the limits. So I use the following:

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[(Sin[x] Sin[2 y] - Sin[ 2 x] Sin[y])^t, y, Assumptions -> t \[Element] Integers]]
```

and the result that I get is

```
1/(1 + t)2 AppellF1[(1 + t)/2, 1 + 2 t, -t, (3 + t)/2, -Tan[y/2]^2, Cot[x/2]^2 Tan[y/2]^2] (Sec[y/2]^2)^( 2 t) (-Sin[2 x] Sin[y] + Sin[x] Sin[2 y])^t Tan[y/  2] (1 - Cot[x/2]^2 Tan[y/2]^2)^-t
```

On substituting /.y-> x (the formula above is 0 at the other limit), the expression that I obtain is
\begin{equation}
\frac{2 \Gamma \left(\frac{t}{2}+\frac{3}{2}\right) \Gamma (t+1) \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \sec ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2 t} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{t+1}{2},2 t+1;t+\frac{t+3}{2};-\tan ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)}{(t+1) \Gamma \left(\frac{3 t}{2}+\frac{3}{2}\right)}
\end{equation}

```
(1/((1 + t) Gamma[3/2 + (3 t)/2]))2 Gamma[3/2 + t/2] Gamma[ 1 + t] Hypergeometric2F1[(1 + t)/2, 1 + 2 t, t + (3 + t)/2, -Tan[x/2]^2] (Sec[x/2]^2)^(2 t) Tan[x/2]
```

However, this is evidently incorrect. For instance, consider the case when $t=2$. The definite integral

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[(Sin[x] Sin[2 y] - Sin[ 2 x] Sin[y])^2, {y, 0, x}]]
```

can now be performed exactly to yield
\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{24} \sin ^2(x) (-36 x+28 \sin (2 x)+\sin (4 x)-24 x \cos (2 x))
\end{equation}

Let's choose a particualr value of $x$, say $0.5$, to see the inconsistency. Plugging in $t = 2,\, x = 0.5$ in the former expression results in $0.0450968$, whereas the latter equation gives $0.000125868$!

I am really puzzled by this discrepancy and would greatly appreciate any help or insights in this regard. I am aware that there is a [bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42464/inconsistent-results-for-equivalent-converging-symbolic-integrals) concerning the ''hanging'' integration order but I am not sure if that is the one responsible for this mess.

Many thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason to believe the indefinite integral will have no jump discontinuity on the path of integration?

Comment: The integrand is a continuous function, and the integration is along the real line ($x$ \in \mathbb{R}). My point is that if the first expression has to be correct, it should be a generic one that works for all values of $t$, but it clearly doesn't!

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Moreover, the output generated by Mathematica is not even a ConditionalExpression, as is often the case, so presumably Mathematica does not require any constraints on $t$ in its evaluation.

Comment: (1) Mathematica never generates `ConditionalExpression` results for indefinite integrals. Those, also known as antiderivatives, are unconditionally correct. Branch cut locations might depend on parameter conditions, but that does not affect correctness of the antiderivatives.

Comment: (2) The integrand can be continuous along some particular path but that does not mean the antiderivative will be everywhere continuous. I'd be surprised for example if it were well behaved with respect to the parameter `t`,

Comment: (3) Maybe it's just me, but I rarely if ever have good experience working with antiderivatives that are expressed in terms of `AppellF1`. Substituting numerical values after the fact just does not seem to go well. But maybe I am jinxed in that regard.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I understand your point. Could you perhaps suggest a way to work around this problem? Is there any way to actually compute this definite integral without running into trouble?

Comment: My only suggestion is to stay within the realm of what definite integration can be handled by `Integrate`. As others will (quickly) observe, even that has its share of bugs, but at least an effort is made in that code to detect path singularities and either correct for them or give up and return unevaluated. One possibility along those lines is to only do the integration under discussion for fixed explicit values of `t`.

Comment: Since $t$ is an "even positive integer", I would start with using the binomial theorem and integrate the relevant sum termwise.

Comment: Note that the integral equals $$(2\sin(x))^t\int_0^x\sin^ty(\cos y-\cos x)^t\mathrm dy\,.$$

Comment: M8 works fine, but I couldn't get 11.3 to evaluate the integral at all.